# Cannot install nvidia driver 515 in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I installed a new system with 22.04 after an old 20.04 system broke down in the same space.

I just can't install the nvidia driver for my rtx 3090.

I downloaded the driver version 515.76 from nvidia for ubuntu 22.04 x64 version and ran it where it was downloaded with sudo ./"nameofdriver".run

The install then gets stuck here:

[image]

I also tried to install with the GUI "additional drivers" and to directly install the nvidia cuda toolkit, but nothing worked.

I feel like the secure mode enabled messes with the installation maybe (too)? If so, how can I deactivate that?

Can someone help?

greetings and thanks.

when I want to install over "additional drivers", I am also asked the additional pw for secure boot and get the error message while installing the driver that way.

[image]

Comment: You might try the 520 driver from the graphics-drivers ppa for your RTX3090. Disabling secure mode is done in your UEFI Settings, before boot.

Comment: thanks! - I solved it now with disabling secure mode in uefi settings.